# How to group numbers in an array in php

Tags: php, arrays

I have a loads of numbers in a string

```
$userlist = '12,17,46,35,32,66,43,64'; //the userlist can be as long as i want 

$arr2 = explode(',', $userlist);
```

i dont now how to get them to output like the follow.

```
12,17

46,35

32,66

43,64
```

Thank You for taking the time to read.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`array_chunk`](http://php.net/array_chunk) to group two together again and then iterate over the groups and implode each again with the `,`. Example ([Demo](http://codepad.org/oiDWrX05)):

```
$userPairings = array_chunk($arr2, 2);

foreach ($userPairings as &$pair)
{
    $pair = implode(',', $pair);
}
unset($pair);

echo implode("\n\n", $userPairings);
```

Output:

```
12,17

46,35

32,66

43,64
```